# Database - is it better to change this db architecture or leave it?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have three tables in my database: Book, Series, Author.

These all have many-to-many relationships between each other.

```
Book - Series: many-to-many
Book - Author: many-to-many
Author - Series: many-to-many
```

So, this means I'll have to add three more tables in my database:

```
1. tableBookSeries, which will have id, idBook, idSeries
2. tableBookAuthor, which will have id, idBook, idAuthor
3. tableAuthorSeries, which will have id, idAuthor, idSeries
```

This means I'll have 6 tables in my database.

Is there a way for optimization of this database or is it good now? Can I shorten the number of tables, and will it do me any good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Opinion there is no direct relation in Author - Series.
An author writes Books only, which happen to be part or not of a Serie.

In a DB would be something like this (Using 5 tables instead of 6):

1. Book - Series: many-to-many - Correct
2. Book - Author: many-to-many - Correct
3. Author - Series: many-to-many - Incorrect (don't do this)

Extra tables:

1. tableBookSeries, which will have id, idBook, idSeries - Correct
2. tableBookAuthor, which will have id, idBook, idAuthor - Correct
3. tableAuthorSeries, which will have id, idAuthor, idSeries - Incorrect (don't do this)

Avoid connection between Author and Series. If you need to know which series are related to an Author, you can still know by searching for his books.
Likewise, to know who wrote a Serie, you can get the list of Authors using the associated Books.

Hope i was helpful

Comment: And if I had Genre instead of Series? Would it be better to have 5 tables then too, or 6?

Comment: I believe it would be the same (5 tables). Genres table containing the List of Genres.. which apply to books, which are written by Authors.

Comment: But the queries would be more simple if I searched directly for author - series, instead of author-book-series.

Comment: Simple, yes (1 less table to Join). But wouldn't be correct. Imagine this scenario: You update AuthorSeries saying for example: Author A is related to a Series B. Then you check the book and there's no book from that author related to that Serie. Then you would need to also update or create a book to make the info reliable. Making table for a "circle" with relations causes lots of problems and can only be done in extreme situations.

Comment: What scenario? Forget Series, talk about Genre.

Comment: I meant: "making tables form* a circle"; And yes, Series or Genres would be exactly the same.